# Remix IDE: Problem with Executing set method

Tags: solidity, remix

I have created a contract and trying to run the contract on the Remix IDE. Following is the code of my contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.9;
contract MyContract{
   
   uint256  peopleCount;
   struct Person{
       string   _firstName;
       string   _lastName;
   }
   Person[]  public  people;
   function addPerson(string memory _firstName, string memory _lastName) public{
      
      people.push(Person(_firstName, _lastName));
      peopleCount += 1;
   }
    function  getFirstName() public view returns (string memory) {
       return people[0]._firstName;
   }
   function   getLastName() public view returns (string memory){
       return people[0]._lastName;
   }
      function setFirstName(string memory _val) public {
      people[0]._firstName = _val;
   }

}
```

I have attached an image when I click the setFirstName(..) tab, I get a trasact button and a box for providing the value of _val argument as shown in the following image:

[image: setFirstName method error]

[vm] from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: MyContract.setFirstName(string) 0x7EF...8CB47value: 0 weidata: 0x639...00000logs: 0hash: 0xf02...883db
transact to MyContract.setFirstName errored: VM error: invalid opcode. invalid opcode The execution might have thrown. Debug the transaction to get more information.

I dont know how to do the debugging, somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an array item `people[index]` with an `index` it has to be a valid position, ie index >= 0 and index < people.length.

In your example `people[0]._firstName = _val` will fail if people is empty. If you first call `addPerson` it should work.